# How to run query in trino and provide output in Avto data format?

Tags: hive, bigdata, trino

I need to get output of trino query through python code. Getting error in Avto formatted use. Csv output is working.
Requirement is to get avro file output format encrypted from a hive table using trino.

Comment: You should include the error you're getting

Answer (score 0):

I assume you used the Trino CLI and its [output format of CSV](https://trino.io/docs/current/client/cli.html#output-formats). As you can see there is no AVRO support there.

However the [Hive connector](https://trino.io/docs/current/connector/hive.html) supports AVRO. So what you would do is create a query that gets your data and then use that in a [CREATE TABLE AS SELECT](https://trino.io/docs/current/sql/create-table-as.html) statement. And you set that table creation statement to use the Hive connector , [set the format to AVRO](https://trino.io/docs/current/connector/hive.html#table-properties) and run the query. Then you have the result in the object storage configured in the catalog used by the Hive connector.

Otherwise there might be [other client tools](https://trino.io/ecosystem/client) that can convert whatever query result you receive from Trino into AVRO, but I am not aware of any.

Lastly .. maybe there is a good [CSV to AVRO converter](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=csv%20to%20avro&atb=v396-1&ia=web)?

Comment: CSV to avro converter would be integrate from external library, right?

Comment: It would be something you do separately outside of Trino. It only makes sense at small scale. Same with client tool usage. it really depends where you want the avro files in the end.. and what you even want to do with them.